# Velocity of different sized balls rolling down the same rail

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, experimental-physics, potential-energy, rigid-body-dynamics

During mechanics lab we conducted an experiment in which we rolled two balls (glass and steel) down an eliptic heightened rail and measured the impact point. The lines of the rail were 0.76~cm. The balls had a different radius, steel - 0.825cm, and glass - 0.75cm. In this experiment **the steel ball got to a shorter range consistently**.
$\\$I tried the following explanation, assuming no work is done by friction (since the ball is mostly rolling):
$$mgh=\frac12mv^2+\frac12Iw^2$$
And using $v=wr$ when $r$ is the radius where the ball is touching the rail, and $I=\frac25mR^2$:
$$gh=\frac{v^2}{r^2}(\frac12r^2+\frac15R^2)$$
so
$$v=\frac{gh}{0.5+0.2\frac{R^2}{r^2}}$$
But the experiment gave an opposite result, for smaller $r$ we get smaller final speed.Are my calculations wrong? Or is there another reason the balls had different speed when leaving the rail?
(My instructor had told me that the key two the answer is the width between the rails so I'm not keen to say that I got opposite results due to friction or sliding).

Comment: Your equation predicts a smaller v with a smaller r.  With a smaller r, the 0.2 term gets bigger (in the denominator).

Comment: something’s not right.  You have $I=2mR^2/5$ but $0.2R^2/r^2$.  Moreover you should have an $r^2$ on the right somewhere.  This is probably not the source of your problems but it should be fixed.  It is also not clear what $r$ is, and in particular if it is fixed or variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last formula there should be a $v^2$ on the left hand side, but it's otherwise ok.  However, we need to consider what r is: The (perpendicular) distance between the axis of rotation and each rail.  If the distance between the rails is $d$, then
$$ R^2 = \left(\frac d 2\right)^2 + r^2. $$
Thus, we get the denominator
$$ \frac12 + \frac15 \frac{R^2}{R^2 - \left(d/2\right)^2}
 = \frac12 + \frac15 \frac{1}{1 - \left(d/{2R}\right)^2}. $$
Since $d$ is the same for both balls, bigger $R$ gives smaller denominator, hence a greater range. This makes sense, too: bigger $R$ means there is less energy placed in the rotation since the ball does not drop as far between the rails and spins in place. So I'm wondering about the exact values from your experiment.